# Can Commitizen update pom.xml file?

Tags: java, maven, devops, semantic-versioning, commitizen

I am working on a Java project and I'm using commitizen to enforce semantic version in CI, when I run the command `cz bump` and `cz changelog` update the .cz.yaml and changelog files with the new version but is not updating the version in pom.xml. Is there a functionality in Commitizen to update this file too?

Additionally: the application is currently being built by Maven

Comment: I have no working solution so far, but at least a idea how this could work. There is a `pre_bump_hook` and in that script you can use different environment variables that provide the new version. And with `mvn versions:set` it should be possible to change the version in the pom.xml. I have the same problem, but not enough time so far to solve it :D

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment above, there is a way to solve this problem and after some testing I'd like to provide you a simple solution now.

I assume you have `.cz.toml` file in place and already configured and use maven as build system for your Java project.

First you should add a `scripts` folder to the maven root. And put 2 shell scripts in there. The first is `prepare_java_version.sh` and the content is:

```
#!/bin/bash
mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=$CZ_PRE_NEW_VERSION
```

The second file is `commit_java_version.sh` and in that file you put the content:

```
#!/bin/bash
mvn versions:commit
```

Now you have to edit the `.cz.toml` file and append these two sections:

```
pre_bump_hooks = [
   "scripts/prepare_java_version.sh"
]
post_bump_hooks = [
   "scripts/commit_java_version.sh"
]
```

And now, you are ready to go.

*Explanation*:
Commitizen calls the `pre_bump_hooks` just before the tag is created, and the shell script modifies the `pom.xml` to the given version. The Version used in the shell script is an environment variable provided by commitizen.

After the commit and the tag are created the `post_bump_hooks` are called and this shell script clean up the maven repo again. The version backup file is removed for example.

*Hint*:
If there is a problem, and you need to revert the version change in the pom.xml just call `mvn versions:revert` and you have the old version. But this only works before the commit is called.

Answer (score 0):

There is an even simpler solution, that works for any language.

In your pom.xml, add a properties that stores the version number (for instance app.version)

```
<app.version>1.0.0</app.version>
```

Then in your commitizen configuration, add the version_files element and point to the newly added property in your pom:

```
version_files = [
    "pom.xml:app.version"
]
```

[Commitizen documentation](https://commitizen-tools.github.io/commitizen/bump/#version_files)